# How to return argument from second function

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

```
const getBunnyPosition = () => {
  MATRIX.forEach((row, rowID) => {
    row.forEach((column, columnID) => {
      if (column === 1) {
        setBunnyImgPosition(rowID, columnID);
      }  
    });
  });
};
```

how can i return the rowID and columnID wihtout calling function with arguments? i tried with destructor return {rowID,columnID}  but i cant get the columnID,in this code i called the second function for get the the indexes but i need them for other functions too

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please provide more context, like what's in `MATRIX`, what `setBunnyImgPosition` expects, etc. Especially important is how you expect this code to work...

Comment: Where do you want to return them to? You can use `map()` instead of `forEach()`, it returns an array of the results of all the callbacks.

Comment: so i need write it with map method for returning the columnID?

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Why do you need to return `rowID` and `columnID`? These are just array indexes, they'll just be consecutive numbers that you can easily calculate from the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: this is 8x8 MATRIX the game board filled by 0 only the bunny position will be 1, the setBunnyImgPosition function need for create img on that position

Comment: If you return all the rowID and columnID, you'll just get something like `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], ...]`

Comment: i want to return the indexes of "1" cause i need to append the bunny img on that position, result will be return the rowID and columnID so i can work with his position

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `forEach`. Use traditional for-loops:

```
const getBunnyPosition = () => {
  for (let rowID = 0; rowID < MATRIX.length; rowID++) {
    const row = MATRIX[rowID];
    for (let columnID = 0; columnID < row.length; columnID++) {
      const column = row[columnID];
      if (column === 1) {
        return {
          rowID,
          columnID,
        };
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just set a variable declared outside the loops.

```
const getBunnyPosition = () => {
  let bunnyPosition;
  MATRIX.forEach((row, rowID) => {
    let columnId = row.indexOf(1);
    if (columnId != -1) {
      bunnyPosition = {rowId, columnId};
    }
  });
  return bunnyPosition;
};
```

The `for` loop solution in the other question is a little better because the outer loop stops when the bunny is found. But for an 8x8 matrix it's not really a significant difference.

Comment: no don't think it's excuse, i just started learning JS that's why

Comment: I was talking about my original answer, not you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `forEach` for this, but `for` loops. Actually for the inner loop you can just use `findIndex` -- as it will break out the loop when it finds a match and return the `columnID` for it.

Secondly, the caller can use destructuring to get the two components of the pair that will be returned (assuming success):

```js
const getBunnyPosition = () => {
  for (const [rowID, row] of Object.entries(MATRIX)) {
    const columnID = row.findIndex(column => column == 1);
    if (columnID > -1) return [rowID, columnID];
  }
};

const MATRIX = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0], // <-- here is the bunny
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
];

const [rowID, columnID] = getBunnyPosition() ?? [];

console.log(rowID, columnID);
```